# Skip indexing and skip storing the not mapped fields

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch

I want to index **only** the fields I explicitly write in the mapping template. I am not interested in the other field so I tried with the option `index:no` in the dynamic_template that matches with all fields and all mapping_type but I cannot reach my expectation with this because I am still able to search on the unwanted fields:

```
     "dynamic_templates": [
        {
           "not_indexed": {
              "match": "*",
              "match_mapping_type": "*",
              "mapping": {
                 "index": "no"
              }
           }
        }
     ]
```

Comment: Can you print your mapping ? GET <index>/<type>/_mapping

Comment: this seems to go against the idea of a schemaless database.

Comment: You are totally right. But I am interested in saving disk space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with

```
"_all": { "enabled": false },
```